# How would one write this out?

Tags: math, scipy

So i have these equations :

[image: formula 1]

[image: hideous formula]

In g, *x* is defined as *X/Sc* (the inverse of the first equation) .   I am trying to write it out correctly but i am fairly new.

update: Is this an equivalent representation,

```
val1 = (r+.5*vol*vol)*(tau-t)
val2 = exp(-alpha*(tau-t)*(r-.5*vol*vol)*(r-.5*vol*vol)/(2*vol*vol))
val3 = vol*vol*sqrt(alpha)/r/2.0
func = lambda g: exp(g*g/2) - val3 / (val1+g*vol*sqrt(tau-t)) / exp(val1+g*vol*sqrt  (tau-t)) / val2
g = fsolve(func,1.5)
exer_price = K * exp( -(r + .5 * vol * vol)*(tau-t) - g * vol * sqrt(tau-t))
```

where exer_price is *Sc*, vol is sigma, *a* is alpha, K is *X*, (tau-t) is *t*. If not, how would i write this out correctly in python?

Comment: Your Python expression do not seem to correspond at all to the mathematical formula that was offered in an image. Are you sure we have the correct image?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that differs from yours, together with the imports needed to execute that code, as well as variable definitions and printing to test it. Note that my variable names and the meanings of `val1` and `val2` differ from your code. Also note that your graphic uses a plus-or-minus, but my code only gives the plus. You can easily modify it as need to give the minus.

```
from math import sqrt, exp, log

alpha = .1
r = .2
sigma = 3
tau = 4
x = 5

val1 = -alpha * (r+(1/2)*sigma**2)**2 * tau / (2*sigma**2)
val2 = sigma**2 / ((2*r/sqrt(alpha)) * x * log(x * exp(val1)))
g = sqrt(2 * log(val2))

print(g)
```

The result of that code is

```
0.6939056413788061
```

There are multiple ways that code could be optimized for speed or brevity, but it meets your stated purpose.

Comment: i forgot to mention (updated now) that x=e^((r+(1/2)*sigma^2)*tau+G * sigma * sqrt(tau))

Comment: @kb: Are you saying that `x` is defined in terms of `g` (as in your update) and also that `g` is defined in terms of `x` (as in the graphic)? If so, you have a very different, more difficult problem than you stated. And is the `G` in your comment the same as the `g` in the update?

Comment: i added some additional information now, i hope this makes it more clear

Comment: @kb: If your latest update is correct, it is indeed true that `x` and `g` are defined in terms of each other. My code above shows how to get `g` from `x`. Is your overall problem to find `x` and `g` that satisfy both equations, given values of the other variables? That is equivalent to finding the intersection points of two curves, a non-trivial problem.

Comment: "Is your overall problem to find x and g that satisfy both equations, given values of the other variables? " yes!